# javascript not changing html attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the horizontal positioning of an applet by changing the `hspace` attribute depending on the screen resolution. The Javascript below does not seem to change anything:

```
<html>
<body>

<applet 
    id="clientApplet"
    archive="client.jar" 
    code="Client.class" 
    width="500" height="530"
    hspace="100">
</applet>

<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var leftMargin = (screen.width-500)/2;

    document.getElementById("clientApplet").setAttribute(hspace, leftMargin);

    window.location.reload()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hspace` needs to be a string:

```
document.getElementById("clientApplet").setAttribute("hspace", leftMargin);
```